# Copy option list from dropdownlist. JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Html code

```
<select id="dropdwon1">
 <option value="1">Item1</option>
 <option value="2">Item2</option>
 <option value="3">Item3</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdwon2"></select>
```

I need copy all options from dropdown1 to dropdown2, using jQuery. Whether it is possible to copy contents simply?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
$('#dropdwon1 option').clone().appendTo('#dropdwon2');
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/VrvvX/)

Comment: @mola10: It does work - the way I wrote it. I just added a link for jsfiddle. Why are you trying to call `val`, `text`, and `html` on a collection of 3 items when they are single item functions???

Comment: @mola10 he is right, stop altering the code and claiming it doesn't work.

Comment: It Works!, thx. "..Why are you trying to call val..." -  2 o'clock in the morning, tired, sorry.

Comment: this works great! i tried without the clone() and it was removing it

Comment: I just figured out that if you're using a jQuery variable to refer to your drop down list (e.g, _dropdown1 = $("#<%= dropdown1.ClientID %>");) then you can clone the items like this: _ddlColumnNames1.find('option').clone().appendTo(_ddldropdown2);

Answer (score 0):

Can you make it "clone" currently (not initial) selected item too?

```
$('#dropdwon1 option').eq(1).attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#dropdwon1 option').clone().appendTo('#dropdwon2');​
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery clone is normaly the way to go but it doesn't work well with items such as 
select check and radio

The work around is  to set the html dom attributes before cloning here is how i do it

```
var selects = $('form').find('select') ;
selects.each ( function ( ) {
var selvalue = $( this ).val() ;
var options = $( this ).find('option') ;
options.each ( function () {
    if ( $( this ).attr( 'value' )  == selvalue ) 
        $( this ).attr( 'selected' , true ) ; 
    });
}) ; 
$('form').clone.appendTo( '#target' )
```

Setting the selected dom attribute to true allow clone to copy the value effectively

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('#dropdwon2')[0].options = $('#dropdwon1')[0].options;
```

Comment: Doesn't work, *.options is read only. Firebug log: setting a property that has only a getter;