# How do you copy one dropdown's options to another dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy option list from dropdownlist. JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433861/copy-option-list-from-dropdownlist-jquery)

In Jquery how do you copy options of one dropdown to another dropdown?

Comment: Comments discussion [moved to chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2027/discussion-between-razor-storm-and-charles-boyung)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#destination').html($('#source').html());
```

or

```
$('#destination').append($('#source').html());
```

`$('something').html()` grabs the html from an element.

`$('something').html('something')` replaces the current html from the element with the new html.

`$('something').append('something')` puts the new html at the end of the old html in the element. (this does not replace).

Answer (score 2):

I'll bite.

```
$('#two').append($('#one').html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CvJbv/

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select_1">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
</select>

<select id="select_2">
 <option>A</option>
 <option>B</option>
</select> 

<button onclick="javascript:CopyLists()">Copy Lists</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function CopyLists()
 {
  var list1 = $('#select_1');
  var list2 = $('#select_2');
  list2.find('option').remove();
  list1.children().each(function () {
    list2.append($("<option></option>").
      attr("value",$(this).val()).
      text($(this).text()));
  });
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's .html() (http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get the contents of the first element, and use it again to write to the contents of the 2nd element. Like so:

$('#options_2').html($('#options_1).html());

Where:

```
<pre>
<ul id="options_1">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="options_2">
<li></li>
</ul>
```

I also agree that you should consider accppeting answers to some of your previous questions.

Comment: Hi, I apologize but I exactly don't know how to accept answer.I did click up button and clicked Yes for Was this post useful to you?. Please let me know If I am missing something.Thanks, Ravi

Comment: @ravi bhartiya, if you want to accept an answer, you can click on the little checkmark below the vote up and down arrows. You need to be signed in to an account to do this.

Comment: @ravi bhartiya You can also click on your username at the top of stackoverflow and see all your previous questions, points, etc.  If you found an answer to your own problem you can post the answer yourself and check yourself as an answer.